# Spring Boot Hibernate TransientPropertyValueException when saving unrelated entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm having issues saving an entity that contains a OneToOne relationship to a tracked object, that has unsaved changes, but the actual reference is null.

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    ... other fields

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "item"
    @JoinColumn(name = "itemId", referencedColumn = "id", nullable = false)
    private Set<ItemFieldData> dataSet;
}

@Entity
public class ItemFieldData {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Item item;
}

@Entity
public class TxnLog {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "itemId")
    private Item item;

}
```

These are simplified versions of my entities. The scenario is as follows.

- I lookup an Item
- I create a new TxnLog (item reference is null)
- I create new ItemFieldData and add it to the item that I looked up. I do not save/flush
- I save/flush some changes made to TxnLog
- **TransientPropertyValueException** is thrown

Code example below :-

```
Item item = itemRepo.findOne(itemId);
TxnLog txnLog = new TxnLog();
txnLog.setSomeFields();

ItemFieldData data = new ItemFieldData("some data");
item.addItemFieldData(data); //inserts into the Set

txnLogRepo.saveAndFlush(txnLog); //txnLog has no reference to my managed item entity yet. When stepping through the code, item in TxnLog is null.
```

At this point an exception is thrown :-

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.items.ItemFieldData.field -> com.items.ItemField; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.items.ItemFieldData.field -> com.items.ItemField
```

So my question is, why is this exception thrown for unsaved/unflushed changes in my managed tracked entity when it is not the entity that is being saved and flushed?

In addition, when saving the TxnLog, even if it does have a reference to Item that is non-null, I do NOT want the save to cascade to item. Hence no CasecadeType on TxnLog.item.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your transaction handling around the code example and/or in the txnLogRepo.

Comment: @Kirinya - There is no transaction handling explicitly setup. TxnLogRepo is a JpaRepository